# Fastest code: Does a list of string contains %s, %d, %f, or %r?

Tags: string, fastest-code

The aim is to create an algorithm to detect that one of the string in a small list of strings contains `%s`, `%d`, `%f`, or `%r`.  All sub-string will start by '%' and be 2 characters longs. Input string will be from 1 to 500 characters with a median of around 20 characters and contain zero to multiple of the possible sub-strings. the number of string in a batch is small, 2 to 5 strings.

Here's the naive python implementation:

```
SUBSTRING_TO_SEARCH_FOR = ["%s", "%d", "%f", "%r"]

def any_substring_in_inputs(inputs: list[str]) -> bool:
    for input in inputs:
        for substring in SUBSTRING_TO_SEARCH_FOR:
            if substring in input:
                return True
    return False
```

The way the values are recovered in inputs isn't important, the algorithm is. The best execution time in a language agnostic environment and in the specified condition win.

There is real world application in pylint, a static analysis tool for python. The best algorithm will be ported to it to detect string with missing formatting parameter automatically.

Comment: Also, it's reccommended to post your challenge in [the Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?answertab=modifieddesc) first so you can get feedback before you post it on the main site.

Comment: Is a submission really supposed to process just one string at a time? Or a batch of strings? With strings as small as 500 bytes, any significant performance improvement would only be measurable when processing a large batch of strings at once -- and most probably with multi-threading, which is why it's important to know on which hardware this is going to be tested.

Comment: I added some precision regarding the batch. Considering the hardware there's no specification, it can run on anything where python code can run (Labtop, AWS X1, Mars Rover...). Of course it's going to run more often on laptops than on Mars Rovers.

Comment: We don't really need to know where the code will eventually run. But challenges posted on this site need to have an objective winning/scoring criterion. In case of `fastest-code`, this implies that you give the specifications of the hardware on which the entries are going to be tested. (Which is usually your own hardware.)

Comment: Maybe I should have chosen fastest-algorithm then ?

Comment: `fastest-code` seems more appropriate here.

Comment: If this is for a real application in pylint, the problem is likely wrong, because `%%s` or `%%%%s` should not count as an occurrence of `%s` (but `%%%s` or `%%%%%s` should).

Comment: Also, there is really no other way to do this other than a linear scan (even regex ultimately does this), so the fastest will obviously end up being in C or Rust. This is uninteresting.

Comment: @seggan How did you understand "The best execution time in a language agnostic environment" ? There's multiple possible algorithms, ultimately the result will be in python. I'm searching for the fastest algorithm not for the fastest language. But thank you for being the first one to comment after down-voting.

Comment: "The best execution time in a language agnostic environment" ultimately disqualifies most answers then? What other algorithms are possible other than a scan?

Comment: Well there's three already. Using regex, the C algorithm that find the first % then check the next characters. the naive one in the question...

Comment: @Jylo I agree with Seggan. The typical way is to search for `%s %d %f %r` using a simple search. The results would vary with very large arrays, and I don't think most answerers will have time to generate millions of strings in one array.

Comment: Ultimately regex turns out to be a linear search too. The C algorithm is a linear search as well, albeit parallell.

Comment: Sure, but the regex implementation once ported to python could be faster than the pure python implementation and searching for a leading ``%`` will definitely be faster than doing ``any(p in string for p in ["%s", "%d", ...]``

Comment: True, but ultimately *it's the same algorithm*. There is not much room for creativity. For example, I can't employ hashmaps or some weird maths to do it.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), About 25ms for 10 million strings.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct
{
    char* ptr;
    size_t len;
} string;

int func(const string* sa, const int n)
{
    int found = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (!found)
        {
            const string* s = sa + i;
            char* ptr = memchr(s->ptr, '%', s->len);
            while (ptr)
            {
                char c = *++ptr;
                if (c == 's' || c == 'd' || c == 'f' || c == 'r')
                {
                    found = 1;
                    break;
                }
                ptr = memchr(ptr, '%', s->len - (ptr - s->ptr));
            }
        }
    }
    return found;
}

void showElapsed(struct timeval start)
{
    struct timeval stop;
    gettimeofday(&stop, NULL);
    printf("%lu ms\n", ((stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000000 + stop.tv_usec - start.tv_usec) / 1000);
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    struct timeval start, stop;
    int ret;
    int count = 10000000;

    puts("creating input...");
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    string* test = malloc(count * sizeof(string));
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        const char* txt = "rkjewj%q werhkhr";
        test[i].ptr = strdup(txt);
        test[i].len = strlen(txt);
        test[i].ptr[15] = 65 + rand() % 60;
    }
    showElapsed(start);

    puts("test false");
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    ret = func(test, count);
    gettimeofday(&stop, NULL);
    printf("%d, expected = 0\n", ret);
    showElapsed(start);

    puts("test true");
    test[count - 1].ptr[7] = 'd';
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    ret = func(test, count);
    gettimeofday(&stop, NULL);
    printf("%d, expected = 1\n", ret);
    showElapsed(start);
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xVRNc9owEL37V2zJUCQwBA5JD05y6y3TW09pJqPIMlawZVeSIWmT305XEgYMdIae6oMtrZ724@1b8zEvmJqv1xdS8aJJBdwYm8pqkt9FHVMhnw9tWqr5ge3NXFpZiq61tUT2rRapyACvNtxGvyPAh@dMD6G2OvFbI3@JJwuFUEn0ASFIEkVSWcgaxQmvlLEb@xAMiyFYHEDRjU@PrhqVwi1Mk@ii1mxeMqjKGmqmWVGIAs@1x@IXiLsgPRg/N6DwMxpRfx48eq8ZkE/eLd3adqe@lm5y6NAwGIFMuqi2YjwvRclzTcz4DvcxDPqDGHCD5dPupVUuCwEEUbRj7ybQugeOvoej0ZbW/cfVgee3MDADeH@HsE731tneWg/okYfjoIHJwPgsOXn8rAVbHB99HFk6zBzSAmNPAn4CZ/SAp527sApvLWyjVcgQdRVFy0qmYPJq9bVgtREpCZoEp9UlK7CHTNtWTkdnVR2CzoV1xipL2Rv57OwxfPt@f7/JqUYd2Iz0@kUDpfmhejEQ4lATu3wygrsiXJzNlsIQZlP/oGhaXHMAbDzy0iOpr8WJt2RSkW2@mqmUuMzItOXnVH3xXinOCbK023DkyrpuhoxwjEJNjTWkx7GXFkWOSDRMJpMePc2Ij7JHSTsbVhjnvMRZrNxQu1hDP/xVRgKozfzUgPoLJ4c0jGAYMfvqYvT04kWsXvo/YSV0vsh1b6cYl8aDfJwEyWHctKkJXqPHEKc9D8HFXyDo5WF29Yiw6yvsoO8ChT5cT5M9LXZV52TWodYzk7HCiHM5xbZhSP93dJfjwA79N4mmMYjXWnAr/E/TixUdt207I2cU2DZlz0jo6hhmgZkvjhj8zfy3omZnFPWxXv8B)

Comment: Using the `haszero()` macro [described here](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZeroInWord), I'd be curious to see if processing 32-bit values and using `haszero(x ^ 0x25252525)` to quickly test if there's a `%` somewhere would result in a significant improvement.

Comment: (Then again, it depends on the hardware. This is only interesting if fetching a 32-bit word is significantly faster than fetching 4 bytes.)

Comment: @Arnauld, do you mean something like [this](https://tinyurl.com/5n6aht8v)? The results looks about the same, and that is with the input optimized so that only the last string contains a `%`. Then again, it may make a difference when you start running it on longer input strings.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't seem any better. Thanks for sharing the results anyway!

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), takes about 150ms for 1 million lines of input

*Edit: messed-up the initial timing by 20x.  Sorry.*

```
/%[adfs]/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifWJ6toO7k6u7pV52WX6RhnWljaAAG1pna2prVBUWZeSUKSolJySmpaekZmVmqKdk5uXn5BYVFSrW16gp2CiWpxSV6JRUlXCWZuakKIONi/qvrq0YnpqQVx@qrA3kwFUDF@impZfp5pTk5/wE)

Outputs the line itself (truthy) if it contains `%a`,`%d`,`%f` or `%s`.  Outputs nothing (falsy) if it doesn't.

This could be considered a baseline answer: I'm assuming that the regex matching is pretty-well optimized, and [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) doesn't add much overhead onto it (as is probably apparent from the rather minimal program).
Note that this is 10x faster on my MacBook with solid-state storage than on [Try it online!].

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, about 3 microsecs for 1000 strings

```python
lambda x:bool([y for y in x if bool([z for z in ["%s", "%d", "%f", "%r"]if z in y])])
```

I don't have the time right now to check for a million strings.

Answer (score 0):

don't short change `awk` -

using a `12.5 mn rows` uncompressed `.txt` test file spanning `1.85 GB`, filled to the brim with multi-byte `UTF-8` characters

— (`349,725,658` multi-byte `Unicode` code points to be exact).

```
rows = 12494275. | UTF8 chars = 1285316715. | bytes = 1983544693.
```

`awk` finished scanning in `887 ms`

(and keep in mind that's inclusive of actually reading `/dev/stdin` instead of just spinning test cases within the program itself)

```
Sun Dec 18 23:26:35 2022 1671423995.300214000

      in0:  219MiB 0:00:00 [2.15GiB/s] [2.15GiB/s] [>] 11% ETA 0:00:00
     out9: 1.36KiB 0:00:00 [1.58KiB/s] [1.58KiB/s] [<=> ]
      in0: 1.85GiB 0:00:00 [2.16GiB/s] [2.16GiB/s] [========>] 100% 
       
( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${m3t}" | mawk2 '/%[dfrs]/'; )  

0.58s user 0.44s system 115% cpu 0.887 total

rows       = 7. | UTF8 chars = 1086. | bytes      = 1388.


Sun Dec 18 23:26:36 2022 1671423996.195609000
```